# writerow() with lists from JSON

Tags: python, json, csv, for-loop

I have the following information extracted from a JSON and saved on a variables. The variables and its information are:

```
tickets = ['DC-830', 'DC-463’, ' DC-631’]

duration = ['5h 3m', '1h 7m' , ‘3h 4m']
```

When I use `writerow()` if the JSON has only one value for example, `tickets = 'DC-830'`, I am able to save the information in a csv file. However, if it has 2 or more values it writes the information in the same row.

This is what I get:

```
Ticket | Duration

['DC-830', 'DC-463’, ' DC-631’] | ['5h 3m', '1h 7m' , ‘3h 4m']
```

Instead I need something like this:

```
Ticket | Duration

DC-830 | 5h 3m

DC-463 | 1h 7m

DC-631 | 3h 4m
```

This is the code:

```
issues_test=s_json[['issues'][0]]
tickets,duration=[],[]
for item in issues_test:
    tickets.append(item['key'])
    duration.append(item['fields']['customfield_154'])

header = ['Ticket', 'Duration']
with open('P1_6.7.csv', 'a') as arc:
    writer = csv.writer(arc)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow([tickets, duration])
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. You just don't understand how `writerow` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the singular name suggests, `writerow()` just writes one row. The argument should be a list of strings or numbers. You're giving it a 2-dimensional list, and expecting it to pair them up and write each pair to a separate row.

To write multiple rows, use `writerows()` (notice the plural in the name). You can use `zip()` to pair up the elements of the two lists.

```
writer.writerows(zip(tickets, duration))
```